# import python file in another directory failed

Tags: python, import, module, directory

I met a very strange problem:

My file structure is like: (core and test are directories)

```
 core
    ----file1.py

    ----__init__.py

 test

    ----file2.py
```

in file2, i wrote:

```
from core import file1
```

result is:

```
ImportError: cannot import name file1
```

Comment: Have you tried relative import like from `..core import file1` ?

Answer (score 2):

Have to create `__init__.py` file inside the test dir:

Because The `__init__.py` files are required to make Python treat the directories as containing packages.

```
parent/
    child1/
        __init__.py
        file1.py

     child2/
        __init__.py
        file2.py
```

From the error:

If run the `child2/file2.py` file directly. You are not able to access `child1/file1.py` from the `child2/file2.py`

Because only from the parent directory can access the child.

If have a folder structure like:

```
parent/
    child1/
         __init__.py
         file1.py
    child2/
         __init__.py
         file2.py
    file3.py
```

If we run the `file3.py` file. Can able to access both `child1/file1.py`, `child2/file2.py` in `file3.py`
Because It is running from the parent directory.

If we need to access `child1/file1` from `child2/file2.py`, We need to set the parent directory:

By running this below command we can achieve it...

```
PYTHONPATH=. python child2/file2.py
```

`PYTHONPATH=.` It refers the parent path. Then runs `child2/file2.py` file from the shell

Comment: sorry. Tried, but failed. still that ImportError

Answer (score 1):

It's not a strange problem, imports simply don't work like that.

From the official documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html

> When a module named spam is imported, the interpreter first searches for a built-in module with that name. If not found, it then searches for a file named spam.py in a list of directories given by the variable sys.path. sys.path is initialized from these locations:
>
> - The directory containing the input script (or the current directory when
>   no file is specified).
> - PYTHONPATH (a list of directory names, with the same syntax as the shell
>   variable PATH).
> - The installation-dependent default.

You could look into relative imports, here's a good source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16985066/4886716

The relevant info from that post is that there's no good way to do it unless you add `core` to `PYTHONPATH` like Shawn. L says.

Comment: hey, thanks man. I have a directory called "core-2" inside "core" ,and the python file inside core-2 can successfully import file1(file1 is in 'core' ). According to the tuto, it should not be able to do that. I misunderstand somewhere?

Comment: That does sound like it would work yes... Truth be told, I'm not sure either. Maybe the second link I posted could be of help, I think it addresses this.

Answer (score 0):

When I tried your case, I got

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file2.py", line 3, in <module>
    from core import file1
ImportError: No module named core
```

The reason is that `Python` does not find `core`. In this case, you need to add `core` to the system path, as shown below (add them at the very beginning of `file2.py`):

```
import sys,os
sys.path.append(path_to_core.py)
```

Or, if you would run it using command line, you could simply put the following at the beginning of `file2.py`

```
import sys,os
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'../'))
```

Here, `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'../')` is to state the path to `file2.py`.