# Unable to import class even though I already have __init__.py files

Tags: python, python-import

I'm trying to import a class in a different directory to another file, but can't seem to get it to work. I know this question has been asked a lot and I have looked through multiple stackoverflow solutions and at https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages

1: [Importing files from different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder)
2: [import python file in another directory failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43975291/import-python-file-in-another-directory-failed)

I want to try to just use the method containing just `__init__.py` file instead of doing an `import sys`

My directory structure is as follows:

```
django_vue/
  __init__.py
  devices/
        __init__.py
        models.py
  lib/
        __init__.py
        my_file.py
```

I'm trying to import the class `Device` from `/django_vue/devices/models.py` to `/django_vue/lib/my_file.py` by:

`from devices.models import Device`

However when I do that I still get the error:

```
from devices.models import Device
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'devices'
```

I'm not sure what I'm dong wrong since I already have the `__init__` file in both directories. Any help is appreciated. Also I'm running python 3.6.

Comment: Are you running a file, module or are you running the django server? Can you post the entire error here?

Comment: Also, as a side note, `__init__.py` files are no longer compulsory, from `python3.6` if I'm not wrong.

Comment: I'm just running a file. So from the terminal I just do ```python my_file.py``` after navigating to ```django_vue/lib/```

Comment: Okay. That's where the problem is. Let me try and fix things if I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the folder structure I'm working with.

```
.
└── django_vue
    ├── devices
    │   └── models.py
    └── lib
        └── file.py
```

When you run

```
$ python file.py
```

python has no way of knowing what's outside the directory.

python can't go back and then into `devices/` just like that.

The easiest way to solve this would be to add the folder `devices/` to `sys.path`. When python imports a module, it searches for the module from `sys.path`. Adding the path to `devices/` would make it available for imports.

Here are my files.

```
# models.py
Device = 'device'
```

```
# file.py
import sys
sys.path.append('..')  # adds the parent dir (which is django-vue/) to path
# django-vue dir has devices/ so now this is available for imports

# importing this works now
from devices.models import Device

print(Device)
```

Output

```
django_vue/lib$ python3 file.py 

device
```

Comment: I got a Django error after that but I think I must have misconfigured something. It no longer gives me the same error so I think it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Think about it your are inside `my_file.py` and import something called `devices`.
How can `python` know where the name `devices` has come from.
It won't search your entire Drive for that module/package

### Relative Import

use a relative import instead. write `from ..devices.models import Device`. This is telling python to go up one directory to the parent directory and that's where it will find the `devices` package. Your `lib` module should now work as a **module**

If you however run the my_file.py package directly (as in `python C:/django_vue/lib/my_file.py`)
**You will still get an error**. Not the same error; the new error will be something like

```py
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

This is happening because you are actually running `my_file.py`

If you think about it why would you want to run `my_file.py` by itself when it is clearly a part of a package. Maybe you are just testing to see if the import works when you use your package. The problem with this is that it makes it seem like your packages relative imports don't work **even though this actually works**.

Create a `main.py` in django_vue and write `from lib import my_file`. This will run your `my_file.py` and you will notice there is no error.

## What's happening here

#### Have you heard of `__package__`?

if you put `print(str(__package__))` in your `my_file.py` and run `my_file.py` directly you will see that it prints `None`.

However if you run `main.py` (that you just created) you will see that when It reaches `my_file.py`, `__package__` will actually be defined to something.

*Ahhh...* you see now it all makes sense; The error you originally got said something about `no known parent package`. If `__package__` is undefined that means there is no relative parent package because the file was obviously run directly instead of as part of a package.

### Consider Absolute imports

you also might want to consider using absolute imports because if you are working on the package you might change it directory structure while developing. so you need to keep changing the import references on the affected files.

Although you can find IDE's with python extensions that automatically to this as you change your directory. I believe `VS Code` does this automatically.

Answer (score -1):

Replace the `__init__` files with `__main__`.

Comment: Your suggestion does not serve the same goal, __init__ file is used for integrating other .py files.