# How to run a python script with modules inside?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have a `test.py` file that I try to run in VSCode with the "Run" button.
I have a string `from file_folder.file import something` inside it. When I try to run my test, VSCode gives me an error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'file_folder'`.

My project tree looks something like this:

```
root_folder -- file_folder -- file.py
            -- test_folder -- my_folder -- test.py
```

Can I make it work in VSCode somehow?

Comment: Could you add an example of your code from `test.py` and the full traceback please?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62502619/unable-to-import-class-even-though-i-already-have-init-py-files

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(1, '<pathToFolder>/file_folder')
from file import something
```

Answer (score 0):

For cross directory access, we usually use relative paths to facilitate code portability.

```
import sys
from os.path import dirname, abspath

project_path = dirname(dirname(abspath(__file__)))
sys.path.append(project_path + "\\file_folder")
from file import *
```